# Passing a numpy array to a tensorflow Queue

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a NumPy array and would like to read it in TensorFlow's code using a [Queue](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#queues). I would like the queue to return the whole data shuffled, some specified number of epochs and throw an error after that. It would be best if I'd not need to hardcode the size of an example nor the number of examples.
I think [shuffle batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch) is meant to serve that purpose. I have tried using it as follows:

```
data = tf.constant(train_np) # train_np is my numpy array of shape (num_examples, example_size)
batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([data], batch_size=5, capacity=52200, min_after_dequeue=10, num_threads=1, seed=None, enqueue_many=True)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
batch.eval()
```

The problem with that approach is that it reads all the data continuously and I cannot specify it to finish after some number of epochs. I am aware I could use the [RandomShuffleQueue](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#RandomShuffleQueue) and insert the data into it few times, but:
a) I don't want to waste epoch*data of memory and b) it will allow the queue to shuffle between epochs.

Is there a nice way to read the shuffled data in epochs in Tensorflow without writing your own Queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create another queue, enqueue your data onto it `num_epoch` times, close it, and then hook it up to your `batch`. To save memory, you can make this queue small, and enqueue items onto it in parallel. There will be a bit of mixing between epochs. To fully prevent mixing, you could take code below with `num_epochs=1` and call it `num_epochs` times.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
num_epochs = 5
queue1_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
queue1 = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=10, dtypes=[tf.int32], shapes=[()])

def create_session():
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.operation_timeout_in_ms=20000
    return tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)

enqueue_op = queue1.enqueue_many(queue1_input)
close_op = queue1.close()
dequeue_op = queue1.dequeue()
batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([dequeue_op], batch_size=4, capacity=5, min_after_dequeue=4)

sess = create_session()

def fill_queue():
    for i in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={queue1_input: data})
    sess.run(close_op)

fill_thread = threading.Thread(target=fill_queue, args=())
fill_thread.start()

# read the data from queue shuffled
tf.train.start_queue_runners()
try:
    while True:
        print batch.eval()
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print "Done"
```

BTW, `enqueue_many` pattern above will hang when the queue is not large enough to load the entire numpy dataset into it. You could give yourself flexibility to have a smaller queue by loading the data in chunks as below.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
queue1_capacity = 2
num_epochs = 2
queue1_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
queue1 = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=queue1_capacity, dtypes=[tf.int32], shapes=[()])

enqueue_op = queue1.enqueue_many(queue1_input)
close_op = queue1.close()
dequeue_op = queue1.dequeue()

def dequeue():
    try:
        while True:
            print sess.run(dequeue_op)
    except:
        return 

def enqueue():
    for i in range(num_epochs):
        start_pos = 0
        while start_pos < len(data):
            end_pos = start_pos+queue1_capacity
            data_chunk = data[start_pos: end_pos]
            sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={queue1_input: data_chunk})
            start_pos += queue1_capacity
    sess.run(close_op)

sess = create_session()

enqueue_thread = threading.Thread(target=enqueue, args=())
enqueue_thread.start()

dequeue_thread = threading.Thread(target=dequeue, args=())
dequeue_thread.start()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about how does it work (possibly pointing to documentation)? 
In particular: why creating a separate thread and enqueuing there all elements `num_epochs` of times won't use too much memory?
And: why would be there mixing of elements if you enqueue the data into the FIFO queue multiple times? Will it be only when one epoch ends and another starts?
Also, calling the whole code `num_epochs` times is far from "a nice way to read the data" :P

Comment: If your queue has capacity 10, then it'll only need space for 10 examples at any one time, and asynchronous queue loading will add more examples as previous examples are consumed. The second queue created by (shuffle_batch) does not know where the epoch ends, so the last batch from an epoch will probably have entries from the next epoch as well.

Comment: Documentation for queues is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html), and also [here](http://yaroslavvb.blogspot.com/2016/05/queues-in-tensorflow.html) are slides from a talk I gave on them

Comment: Do you possibly know why I get the following error only when the op timeout is specified? 
`CancelledError: Dequeue operation was cancelled
  [[Node: shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]`

Comment: I like specifying timeouts because the default timeout is infinity and who has time to wait this this long? In practice you could use larger value like 120 seconds (loading cuda stuff for the first time can take 60 seconds). You can get messages like above when there are stragglers -- ie perhaps there aren't enough items to fill the last batch, so it wants to wait forever, and timeout terminates the waiting. You could instead use `dequeue_up_to`

Comment: Thanks! I tried increasing the timeout, but didn't expected that it may be needed to be set to >10 seconds.