# Numpy array to Tensorflow queue

Tags: multithreading, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I wish to pass a two numpy arrays (data and labels) to a tensorflow queue num_epochs times, I understand this has already been answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068259/passing-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensorflow-queue).
However, in the answer the author uses the **feed_dict** functionality to populate the queue, which according to this [post](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-optimise-your-input-pipeline-with-queues-and-multi-threading-e7c3874157e0) slows down computation when using tensorflow in a distributed architecture because the program needs swap between Python and the underlying C++ wrapper.

My question is: is it possible to do this without using **feed_dict**?

Comment: To be confirmed, but I don't think using `feed_dict` in the context of the queue will slow ou down. After all, the enqueue operations will happen in a different thread and asynchronously so it should mask the Python/C++ swap. In the model subgraph, data will be fed though the dequeue operation which i part of the same subgraph. That's the main reason of these queues : having 2 asynchrone subgraphs such that I/O (but also Python/C++) can be hidden.

Comment: Perhaps it won't slow me down that much, it's just from reading that second post I mentioned it seems queues will be the way to go in the future and also they make for more readable code. Ideally it would be nice to have something like the tf.TextLineReader but for files with numpy arrays...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: if you use a queue, whatever the way you would feed it, I believe you will benefit from the queue as the second post describes. Indeed you'll get two asynchrone sub graphs : one for retrieving/fee data into the queue, the second being your model which access the data through a dequeue operation, making it independent from any IO, C++/Python cost happening in the first subgraph..

Comment: Oh! ok, that makes sense, I will give it a go a see if there are any performance improvements. When I started using distributed mode (without actually using more machines yet) the fact that I using feed_dict to feed the batches slowed me down by factor of 4 (vs not using distributed mode)

Comment: Let us know, I would be really curious to know about the performance results.

Comment: Will do, hopefully distributed mode with the same amount of machines only deteriorates the performance slightly if coded correctly...

Comment: Followup: adding large numpy arrays to the queue crashed my machine, using feed_dict and without using it (I figured out how to do it). Since I was running out of memory I ended up converting my arrays to a TFRecord file and used a queue to read each array form disk individually.