# Error in tf.train.batch - FIFOQueue is closed and has insufficient elements

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use queues in Tensorflow (version 1.6) to generate batches of characters:

```
import tensorflow as tf

list1 = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(4,))
list2 = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(4,))

char1, char2 = tf.train.slice_input_producer([list1, list2])
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.initialize_local_variables())
sess = tf.Session()
char1_batch, char2_batch = tf.train.batch([char1, char2], 2, 20)

with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    while True:
        try:
            x, y = sess.run([char1_batch, char2_batch], feed_dict={list1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], list2: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']})
            print x, y
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print "Queue Empty!!"
            break

sess.close()
```

However, I get an OutOfRangeError at the start of the loop itself. I checked other similar posts. Most of them suggest initializing local variables via tf.initialize_local_variables(), but that doesn't help. The error is probably because the batch operation tries to deque before the other thread has enqueued any characters in char1 and char2, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you not seeing this possible cause ?            _INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype string and shape [4]
  [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_STRING, shape=[4], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I turn on debugging like this in your code

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)
```

I see this error followed by the error mentioned in the question.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>,
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype string and shape [4] [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_STRING, shape=[4], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

So based on that I tried two different methods. First I removed the batch call and that simple case worked. The second variation can process batches but involves the threading framework. Threads are supposed to be used carefully.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import threading

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

list1 = tf.placeholder(tf.string,name="x")

queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50, dtypes=[tf.string], shapes=[()])

enqueue_op = queue.enqueue_many(list1)

dequeue_op = queue.dequeue()
data_batch = tf.train.batch([dequeue_op], batch_size=2, capacity=40)

init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.initialize_local_variables())

sess = tf.Session()

def put():
    sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={list1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']})

mythread = threading.Thread(target=put, args=())
mythread.start()

tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)

try:
    while True:
        print (sess.run(data_batch))
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print ("Queue empty")


sess.close()
```

This is a variation that is discussed [here](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-optimise-your-input-pipeline-with-queues-and-multi-threading-e7c3874157e0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068259/passing-a-numpy-array-to-a-tensorflow-queue)

The output is this.

```
   [b'a' b'b']
   [b'c' b'd']
   [b'e' b'f']
```

Comment: So, I was starting both the enqueue thread and the batch thread simultaneously when I called tf.train.start_queue_runners(), and when batch thread called dequeue on list placeholders, they were empty, causing the error. Starting the enqueue thread beforehand solved it. Thanks a lot!!